# Create Alias for Function in .profile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, .profile

I want to run executables in my $GOPATH/bin directory without having to **cd** there so I've added the following to my .profile file:

```
    export GOBIN=$HOME/go-workspace/bin
    function _rungo() { "$GOBIN" "@$1" }
    alias rungo='_rungo'
```

The alias definition is on line 28.
The idea is that on the command line I type **rungo executable_name** to run an executable.

When I log into my account, I get the following error:

```
     line 31: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I comment out the alias definition I get this error

```
    line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

So obviously my function definition is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why define an alias instead of just naming the function `rungo` to start?

Comment: If just naming the function is sufficient that would be fine. I haven't done Linux for a while so I don't know what the best solution is.

Comment: Use `shopt -sq expand_aliases` before `alias...` (Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt, man 1 bash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare a bash function as a one liner, you need to include a `;` before you end the function, thus the working function should be

```
function _rungo() { "$GOBIN" "@$1" ;}
```

EDIT:

Answer to the following:

> Thanks Karoly and Zuzzuc. I've decided to keep the function as a one-liner so I added the ; When I issue a command like "rungo hello" I get a message that says /home/smurphy/go-workspace/bin is a directory Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Well, first of all you do not need to write `function myFunction()` because `myFunction()` works just as well.

Moving on to the real question, you does not need to make the alias rungo, just name the function rungo instead. Creating the alias is just a waste of time, as it will redirect its input to the function you created.

Partly the reason it failed, is because aliases can **not** take arguments. I am also not sure wether you need the "@" in "@$1".

I does also think it would be better to use `exec "$GOBIN/$1"` instead of just `"$GOBIN" "@$1"`.

**Solution**

Change

```
export GOBIN=$HOME/go-workspace/bin
function _rungo() { "$GOBIN" "@$1" }
alias rungo='_rungo'
```

to

```
export GOBIN=$HOME/go-workspace/bin
function rungo() { exec "$GOBIN/$1" ;}
```

Hoped this helped!

Comment: Thanks Karoly and Zuzzuc. I've decided to keep the function as a one-liner so I added the `;` When I issue a command like "rungo hello" I get a message that says _/home/smurphy/go-workspace/bin is a directory_ Is it possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: I'll edit my answer instead because it supports better formatting.

Comment: Thanks, Zuzzuc. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The function closing bracket has to be in a new line. Alternatively, use `;`.

To illustrate the problem, look at this example:

```
function rungo() { echo X }
}
rungo    # outputs: X }
```